# German exercises for Abitur. Translate into english

Tags: functions, translation-request, mathematical-german

Please help me to translate into English the last three questions(f,g,h) from this photo. Can you give me some ideea to solve this problems?
[image]

Can you recommend me some math, physics dictionary?

Thanks!

Comment: It's sickening to see multiple exercises of this kind in a German "Abitur" of 2013.

Comment: Why?Because for me these exercise seems to be interesting and I want to understand totally what means every exercise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

f) Show that the function $F_0$ given by
$$F_0(x):=4 \ln (x+1) + {4\over x+1}\qquad (x>-1)$$
is a primitive of $f_0$.

Between the graph of $f_0$ and the $x$-axis one has in the first quadrant a piece of area extending to infinity. Check whether this area is finite.

g) The function $f_1$ has to be approximated by a function $g_{c,b}$ of the form
$$g_{c,b}(x):=c\cdot e^{bx}\qquad(x>-1)\ .$$
How should we choose $c$ and $b$ such that the graphs of $f_1$ and $g_{c,b}$ intersect in two points $P_1$, $P_2$ with $x_1=0$ and $x_2=1$?

h) Compute for the values $c$ and $b$ found in g) the angle between the two graphs at the intersection point $P_1$.

PS: In order to solve h) compute the slopes of the two graphs at $P_1$ and use the formula for $\tan(\alpha-\beta)$.

Comment: Can you give me some idea for h)? thanks